# Why does Hibernate execute select currval in persist occasionally?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jdbc-postgres

Sometimes and seems randomly Hibernate executes query like that during persist operation:

```sql
select currval('MY_TABLE_NAME_id_seq');
```

Entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE_NAME")
public class MyEntity {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

}
```

Code:

```java
@Transactional
public void persistMyEntity(String name) {
   MyEntity entity= new MyEntity (name);
   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(entity);
}
```

Generated sql:

```sql
insert into MY_TABLE_NAME(name) values ('xyz');

select currval('MY_TABLE_NAME_id_seq');
```

But usually `select currval` is not executed. Is there any explanation about that?

BTW my question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480622/jpa-hibernate-select-currval-on-non-existing-sequence-relation) but the solution in the question is not worked for me.

Note:

My_TABLE_NAME ddl sql:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table_name (
   id bigserial NOT NULL,
   name character varying(256) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT my_table_name_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Hibernate properties:

```java
Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.connection.release_mode", "auto");
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.archive.autodetection", ARCHIVE_AUTODETECTION);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", true);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", false);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.use_scrollable_resultset", true);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary", true);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 20);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.order_inserts", true);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.order_updates", true);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data ", true);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.cache.region_prefix", "hibernate.cache");
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", false);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", false);
sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
```

- PostgreSQL version: 11.5.
- hibernate.dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
- Hibernate version: 5.4.5.Final
- PostgreSQL JDBC Driver: postgresql-9.4

Comment: Could you please provide the `hibernate.cfg.xml` settings? What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @SternK I added.

Comment: Could you please also show your table `MY_TABLE_NAME`  ddl sql. And what version of PostgreSQL JDBC Driver do you use?

Comment: What value do you use for the property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`?

Comment: @SternK I also added other informations you wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-identity):

> **2.6.10. Using IDENTITY columns**
>
> For implementing identifier value generation based on IDENTITY columns, Hibernate makes use of its `org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator` id generator which expects the identifier to be generated by INSERT into the table. IdentityGenerator understands 3 different ways that the INSERT-generated value might be retrieved:
>
> 1. If Hibernate believes the JDBC environment supports `java.sql.Statement#getGeneratedKeys`, then that approach will be used for extracting the IDENTITY generated keys.
> 2. Otherwise, if `Dialect#supportsInsertSelectIdentity` reports true, Hibernate will use the Dialect specific INSERT+SELECT statement syntax.
> 3. Otherwise, Hibernate will expect that the database supports some form of asking for the most recently inserted IDENTITY value via a separate SQL command as indicated by `Dialect#getIdentitySelectString`

You can specify `java.sql.Statement#getGeneratedKeys` explicitly in the following way:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</property>
```

You do not do it, so, hibernate somehow treat its value as `false`. Then hibernate checks value of `dialect.getIdentityColumnSupport().supportsInsertSelectIdentity()`. It is `false` for your case. And then hibernate follows by the last way. See the implementation of the [PostgreSQL81IdentityColumnSupport](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/identity/PostgreSQL81IdentityColumnSupport.java) class. The method *getIdentitySelectString* generates exactly the same sql that you complained about.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as far as I understand from hibernate docs  `hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys` is `true` by default. I also observe that usually hibernate gets id without generating `select currval` sql. But raerly  `select currval` sql is generated. So can we say that it's a kind of bug of JDBC driver or Hibernate? Is it a known issue? Why is this happening do you have any idea?

Comment: I do not see from hibernate docs that `hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys` is `true` by default. I see that `By default, it tries to detect the driver capabilities from connection metadata.`. I tried to reproduce your problem by using exactly your version of jdbc driver, but without success. Maybe it is somehow related to the environment your application running in.