# Current value of sequence "PUBLIC.TEST_ID_SEQ" is not yet defined in this session; SQL statement: select currval('test_id_seq')

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have problem with Postgres and Hibernate, it works perfectly fine in production code, but when I try to write integration tests, i get following error during entity save:

```
 Current value of sequence "PUBLIC.TEST_ID_SEQ" is not yet defined in this session; SQL statement: select currval('test_id_seq')
```

schema.sql:

```
   CREATE TABLE public.test
(
    id        bigserial NOT NULL,
    description      varchar   NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE SEQUENCE public.test_id_seq MINVALUE 1;
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
}
```

I am saving new entity with standard CrudRepository.save() method. What is wrong? Why in production code it works fine?

Comment: You probably have to to next value before you can do current value.

Comment: But why hibernate doesn't handle this?

Comment: @Klapek Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60488292/why-does-hibernate-execute-select-currval-in-persist-occasionally)

Answer (score 0):

If you use BIGSERIAL, than you shouldn't create sequence. Postgres create one.